# R - iterate over list of files

Tags: r, list, file, lapply

I have a list of files with some data that I want to read in to R and then iterate over each file for some calculations.
So far I was able to read the files with the following code:

METHOD1

```
filenames<-list.files(pattern="*.txt")
mynames<-gsub(".txt$", "", filenames)
for (i in 1:length(mynames)) assign(mynames[i], read.table(filenames[i]))
```

However when I try to apply some function to "names" it just says NULL

```
lapply(mynames,nrow)
```

I know that it could be easier to read the files directly into a list

METHOD2

```
temp<-list.files(pattern="*.txt")
myfiles<-lapply(temp, read.table,skip="#")
```

and then do lapply to that list `lapply(myfiles,nrow)`, but this just looses the information about which file produced each list.

Is there any way to circumvent this with either method in order to keep tracking the relation list-file?

Thanks

Comment: I'd say `names` is a vector, not a list, you can check with `is.list(names)`. By the way, not a very good idea to call a variable `names`as it is already a function in R...

Comment: @CathG thanks, corrected names to mynames. is.list(mynames) returns FALSE, but even if I do "mynames<-as.list(mynames)" and then "lapply(mynames,nrow)", still returns NULL for all elements.

Comment: @PedroA Try this `df1 <- data.frame(Col1=1:5, Col2=6:10); df2 <- data.frame(Col1=rnorm(10), Col2=sample(10)); mynames1 <- ls(pattern="^df\\d+"); sapply(mget(mynames1), nrow)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first method, try

```
  sapply(mynames,function(nameoffile){nrow(get(nameoffile))})
```

Comment: is there any way to do iterate over several nameoffile? since I can have a few.

Comment: @CathG Another option might be `sapply(mget(mynames), nrow)`

Comment: @akrun, this doesn't work for me: "Error in mget(mynames) : invalid first argument"

Comment: @PedroA It would work if `mynames` are dataframe objects in the global environment.

Comment: @CathG Yes, for getting `dataframes` as such, I would use `lapply`.  But, here (I didn't read the post, only skimmed through your reply), the intention is to just get `nrow`.  `lapply` gets that in a list, which you need `unlist` if you need a vector.  But `sapply` will get ` a vector.

Comment: @CathG I use `mget` regularly, so I remembered it.

Answer (score 4):

For method 2 you could easily use seomething like

```
temp <- list.files(pattern = "*.txt")
myfiles <- lapply(temp, read.table, skip = "#")
names(myfiles) <- temp
```

In this way the `names` attribute stores the filenames and you do not clutter your working environment with new variables.

So when you want to iterate over the content you can use `lapply(myfiles, function(.) nrow(.))` or if you need to iterate over both the filename and the content you could so something like `lapply(names(myfiles), function(.) nrow(myfiles[[.]]))`